# API routing on react Server side in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, server-side, react-router-redux

I have an application where Client side is in react and server is in JAVA. Both are deployed on different Linux servers. My requirement is to call the JAVA API via react server , currently the browser(client) is directly calling the JAVA server.

Need to create a router to accomplish the above requirement. Not getting any source on web.